# Get scrset from image

Tags: jquery, html

I've this code :

```
<img src="/images/doux-1-199x300.jpg" alt="" 
width="199" height="300" 
srcset="/images/doux-1-199x300.jpg 199w, /images/doux-1.jpg 371w" 
sizes="(max-width: 199px) 100vw, 199px">
```

What I want is to get the url : `/images/doux-1.jpg`

I try something with jQuery using `.attr()`

```
var url = $(img).attr('srcset');
```

How can I target only this url : `.attr()`

Comment: Middle one always? `$("img").attr("srcset").split(" ")[1]`